# How to send data from one model/ controller to another in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not sure how to achieve this:

1. User enters email on page 1
2. On page 2, User doesn't have to enter email again, because it has persisted (again across controllers/ models)

Yet another way of saying it using code snippets below:

1. User enters email "test@gmail.com" in signups/new
2. Email is posted to signups/create, so now the model signups has one new row of data with "test@gmail.com"
3. User redirected to requests/new
4. On requests/new, I'd like the same email that the user just signed up with to be immediately accessible, i.e., @requestrecord.email = "test@gmail.com" in the new action, so User doesn't have to re-enter it and post to requests/create

**Signup Controller code**

```
def new
    @signup = Signup.new
end

def create
    @signup = Signup.new(signup_params)
    if @signup.save
        redirect_to new_request_path
    else
        render new_signup_path
    end

end
```

**Request Controller code**

```
def new
    @requestrecord = Request.new
end

def create
    @requestrecord = Request.new(request_params)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the user's email in a session variable:

```
def create
  @signup = Signup.new(signup_params)
  if @signup.save
      session[:user_email] = @signup.email
      redirect_to new_request_path
  else
      render new_signup_path
  end
end
```

and then you can use it as needed with `session[:user_email]` in your Request controller.

Comment: The OP may wish to read up on: http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms to clarify this